# How to display a JSON object with php and cURL?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm very new to php (I know next to nothing, in fact) and I'm trying to display an object from a JSON string on a website (probably not the right terminology but you know... I'm new...). Here's the cURL code I'm using:

```
$url="http://mc.gl:8081/?JSONSERVER=lobby";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

Then I have this that's supposed to do something (I really dont understand it)

```
// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

Annnnnddd.... what do I do next? I've done a lot of googling and nothing seems to work. Here's the string that I should be getting:

```
{"lobby":{"playeramount":1,"players":{"MisterErwin":"MisterErwin"}},"API-Version":"1","return":true}
```

and I want to echo "**playeramount**".

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Why you used CURL (is there any special reason), Have you tried ajax (using jquery) its more simple. check this `http://www.lennu.net/2012/06/25/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) function in PHP is used to display structured information about variables. It is usually used for debugging and has nothing to do with the JSON decode.

In this case, the `$result` variable will contain the JSON string you need. To decode it, use PHP's built-in function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$json = json_decode($result); // decode JSON string into an object
```

Note: It's also possible to get an associative array by passing `TRUE` as the second parameter to `json_decode()`.

Once you have the object, you can traverse it to get the required value:

```
echo $json->lobby->playeramount;
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TYIyh0)

Comment: Thank you for you swift response! However, it didn't work for me. Am I supposed to replace `// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result));` with `$json = json_decode($result);`?

Comment: For some reason, it's still not working. Obviously it works on codepad.viper-7.com so there shouldnt be anything wrong with your code. I'm using drupal and it returns this error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 49 of /home/thenet/public_html/sites/all/modules/custompage/test1.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 49 of /home/thenet/public_html/sites/all/modules/custompage/test1.tpl.php).` If you think you can help, I would really appreciate it. If not, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the result as an **`associative array`**, you can do like this too [By passing a **true** flag in the `json_decode()` function]

```
<?php
$str='{"lobby":{"playeramount":1,"players":{"MisterErwin":"MisterErwin"}},"API-Version":"1","return":true}';
$str=json_decode($str,true); // Setting the true flag 
echo $str['lobby']['playeramount']; //Outputs 1
```